# Safely extracting partial data from pickled objects

Tags: python, pickle

I've got a pickled instance of an object and have to accept these pickled instances from untrusted sources. There is internal state (just an array of integers) that I can use to recreate the instance without executing any code of the pickled object. My question therefore is if it is possible to extract only some data objects from a pickle without executing any code from it.

Comment: Why not use something other than `pickle` if you need to accept untrusted data? An array of integers could be represented in JSON, for example.

Comment: My problem is that I have to deal with a large number of legacy objects that I have to accept (and which are obviously already serialized using pickle). The next best solution if extraction of data from pickles is not possible is to require people to run a converter. While this works it isn't a procedure I want to impose on my users.

Comment: Note the red box at the top of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) - `pickle` is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Really? I am fully aware that pickle is not the right tool for this job. That's why I am asking if there is a way to safely extract the data and then convert it to something more suitable without requiring all my users to recreate their rather large and sophisticated objects.

Comment: The short answer is trivially *"yes"*: you could reimplement what `pickle` does (for the specific protocol version you're using), limiting the parsing to the specific data you need to extract. The long answer is too long for SO.

Answer (score 1):

An idea might be to read the pickled objects from the files as strings, then use `pickletools.dis` to see what's in them… only allowing a specific list of commands ('`STOP`', '`INT`', …) to be in the second column.  That would negate the pickle having any of the types of objects that you are worried about, and if you are only targeting a very specific list of basic python objects, you ***might*** be able to do this safely.

Here's what you get with `pickletools.dis`:

```
>>> import pickletools
>>> import pickle           
>>> 
>>> p1 = pickle.dumps(1)
>>> p2 = pickle.dumps(min)
>>> 
>>> pickletools.dis(p1)
    0: I    INT        1
    3: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 0
>>> pickletools.dis(p2)
    0: c    GLOBAL     '__builtin__ min'
   17: p    PUT        0
   20: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 0
>>>
```

It's better than writing a full pickle parser, and possibly doable if you only want to allow simple objects like `INT`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but only if you parse the data yourself, not relying on pickle which could lead to arbitrary code execution. A very simple example of doing could be

```
import pickle
import re

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.internal_list = l
        self.foo = 2
        self.bar = 24

# Create a pickled version of an object
t = Test([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
pickle.dump(t, open("test.pickle",'w'))

def find_last_integer(s):
    """ Parses a string to return the integer that it ends with
        e.g. find_last_integer("foobar312") == 312
    """
    return int(re.search(r"\d+$", s).group())

# Load the pickled data
data = open("test.pickle").read()
listdata = data[data.find("(lp"):].split('\n') # Assumes that the class will only contain one list
                                               # if you need more then look for all lines starting "(lp"

nelements = find_last_integer(listdata[0])

# Each element of the list should be of the form "In" or "aIn"
reconstructed = [find_last_integer(elem) for elem in listdata[1:nelements+1]]
print reconstructed
```

Note that I've only tested the above code in python 2.7.8 YMMV if you use it with other versions.

Comment: I feared that writing my own pickle parser would be the only way to solve this. I am obviously not going to do it as realistically I'm going to introduce more exploitable bugs than it removes. I'll just require users to convert to some sensible serialization format and that's it.