# IO-Efficient Way in Python To Retrieve Original File after Intentionally Corrupting/Encrypting Them

Tags: python, algorithm, file, encryption, io

Say we have a file (~100 GB) containing some data on the machine

```
import pickle
import random

# Generate & save the example data file
SOME_LARGE_NUMBER = 10_000_000_000
data = [random.random() for _ in range(SOME_LARGE_NUMBER)]
with open('data.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Using Python, what is an efficient way to corrupt & retrieve part of the file contents (including even changing a single byte) such that

1. Reading the corrupted file directly in Python will result in no meaningful data (i.e. you cannot get back the original Python list)
2. It is extremely quick to reconstruct and read a specific portion (for example, read the element of the list at a specific index) of the original data from the un-corrupted data
3. Does not require storing the entire (~100 GB) file contents in memory
4. Does not require temporarily storing a (~100 GB) temp file on the drive

Thanks!

```
def corrupt_file(filepath):
    # Corrupts the file data and saves to disk
    #... taking 1-5 secs per 100 GB file is fine

def read_original_data_at_index(filepath, index):
    # Opens the corrupted file and 
    # reads the original data at the list index `index`
    # ... should recover original data at `index` ideally in under 0.1-0.2s
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be impossible to fulfill 1 and 2 simultaneously? Creating an error when attempting to read the file seems to run counter to being able to reconstruct the data, because it would require reading at-least some portion of the corrupted file.

Comment: @Stephen Guess I mean to say that if you try to read the corrupted file using `pickle` without performing any additional work to reconstruct the original data, you will not get back any meaningful data. Updated #1 and #2

Comment: Can you define "meaningful data?" And in the worst case, every single byte is corrupted, and would involve replacing the entire file from the original. Do you want that to happen in 0.2 seconds too?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Meaningful data will be the original list elements that was generated and pickled into a file `data.dat`, like in the example Python code in the question. Non-meaningful data will be anything except the exact same Python list. Corrupting the file can take more than 0.2 seconds, maybe 1-5 seconds?

Comment: Oh, so 2 just deals with reading the original file and does not touch the corrupted file?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Correct! Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

This actually turns out to be relatively easy if the goal is to just break pickle.

```
def corrupt_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb+') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        char = f.read(1)
        char = (ord(char) + 1) % 256
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(bytes([char]))
```

This function takes the first byte of data in the file, and replaces it with a byte that is offset by 1 (it could also be modified to change a random byte for better security). It only reads that single byte from the file, which is generally fast.

Then we have:

```
def read_original_data_at_index(file_path, index):
    with open(file_path, 'rb+') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        char = f.read(1)
        char = (ord(char) - 1)
        if char < 0: char+=256
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(bytes([char]))
        f.seek(0)
        original = pickle.load(f)
        return original[index]
```

which fixes the corrupted file on disk, uses `pickle` to convert it back into an object, and returns the index.

If you're trying to get the data back without loading the entire pickled object from the file, you'll likely have to use something like the answers mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495094/safely-extracting-partial-data-from-pickled-objects) thread.